# Mapping output file C (windows)

Tags: c, windows, mapping

I have a problem with mapping a .txt file to memory that doesn't have any inserted data yet, but I keep getting error 1006 when calling the CreateFileMapping function. I have already resolved the mapping to memory for Linux and now I wanted to convert it to Windows, but I can't figure it out.

This is the code for Linux:

```
// Open the output file
int output_file = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
if (!output_file) {
  printf("Unable to create file.");
  exit(1);
}

// Get the size of the output file
size_t output_file_size = strlen(input_data_without_comments);

// Set length to file
ftruncate(output_file, output_file_size);

// Map the output file into memory
char *output_data = mmap(NULL, output_file_size, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, output_file, 
0);
if (output_data == MAP_FAILED) {
  printf("Error: failed to map output file\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

This is code for windows that I have:

```
// Open the output file
printf("Open the output file\n"); 
HANDLE output_file = CreateFile(argv[2], GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, 
NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, NULL);
if (output_file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
  _tprintf(_T("Error: could not open output file '%s'\n"), argv[2]);
  exit(1);
}

// Initializing variables for output length
DWORD output_file_size = 0;
DWORD high_output_file_size = 0;

// Get length of the output file
output_file_size = GetFileSize(output_file, &high_output_file_size);
printf("Size of the output_file: %d\n", output_file_size);

// Output file mapping
printf("Output file mapping\n"); 
HANDLE output_file_mapping = CreateFileMapping(output_file, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0, 
NULL);
if (output_file_mapping == NULL) {
  _tprintf(_T("Unable to create file mapping (output_file)\n"));
  _tprintf(_T("Last error was: %i"), GetLastError());
  exit(1);
}

// Set length to file
printf("Set length to file\n");
SetFilePointer(output_file, output_file_size, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
SetEndOfFile(output_file);

// Map the output file into memory
printf("Map the output file into memory\n");
char *output_data = MapViewOfFile(output_file_mapping, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 
output_file_size);
if (output_data == NULL) {
  printf("Error: failed to map output file\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Please don't spam unrelated tags. If you program in C then don't tag the completely different language C++.

Comment: I also printed the steps and this is where I ended up:                                             
(Open the output file)
(Size of the output_file: 0)
(Output file mapping)
(Unable to create file mapping (output_file))
(Last error: 1006)

Comment: I hope you're mapping files to write them as an experiment of sorts and not as some "I hope this will run faster" performance enhancement.  Because it won't be faster.  In fact, it will almost certainly be *slower* than just writing it.  Mapping a file creates virtual memory mappings in your process address space.  Those are *expensive* operations (both ways - when you unmap the file they're removed), and if you only access the page once, paying that price is not worthwhile, and the write operation will almost certainly be slower than just using C-standard or OS-specific write functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `1006` is `ERROR_FILE_INVALID` ([the Microsoft error code reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1000-1299-) is very useful).

Searching for `ERROR_FILE_INVALID` in the [`CreateFileMapping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga) documentation gives:

> An attempt to map a file with a length of 0 (zero) fails with an error code of `ERROR_FILE_INVALID`. Applications should test for files with a length of 0 (zero) and reject those files.

You can't create a mapping of an empty file. You need to set the size *before* you create the mapping, not after.